# Using a 2d array in a function to return a pointer to the row in which a number appears most

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

i am trying to write a code that uses a function that takes as parameters a two dimensional array and an integer and returns a pointer to the row in which that number appears the most. then i want to use that function in a program which assigns random variables to a 5x5 array, asks a user to search for a certain integer of their choice and the uses that function to display the elements of the row in which the number appears most.

ive been trying to work with this code for so long but i just can't seem to get it right. this is what i have written so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define COLS 5

 int *find(int arr[][COLS],int num){

    int i, j;
    static int count[100];
    int a ,b, repeated;

    for(i=0; i<6; i++) {

      for(j=0; j<6;j++) {

        if(arr[i]==num){
        count[i]++;
        }
      }
   }

   for(a=0;a<5;a++){
   printf("count[%d]=%d\n",a,count[a]);
   repeated=count[0];
    for(b=0;b<5;b++){
        if(repeated<count[i])
        repeated=count[i];
       }
       printf(" %d", repeated);

   }


 }

int main (){

int number;

srand(time(NULL));
int arr[5][5];
 int i, j;
   for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
      for(j=0; j<6; j++) {
            arr[i][j]=rand()%10;
         printf("Element[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, arr[i][j]);
      }
   }

   printf("\n");



   printf("Find integer:");
   scanf("%d",&number);
   *find(arr[i][j],number);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: _pointer to the row_,  Will a simple integer from `0` to `numRows-1` work?

Comment: Indices for `int arr[5][5];` are valid for only `0 - 4`,  i.e. C arrays are accessed via zero based indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things in your code to suggest that [a good C book](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNRsD8KlzW0zEi5k8u8N-fpqlCBA8A%3A1575403506202&source=hp&ei=8r_mXfieCoPT-gSg5auoBw&q=a+good+C+book&oq=a+good+C+book&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l2.1373.3879..5606...1.0..0.94.751.13......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0j33i22i29i30.wlW718xPbGk&ved=0ahUKEwj43_Oyo5rmAhWDqZ4KHaDyCnUQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) should be consulted.  A few summary items to note:

- C arrays indices are zero based, i.e. int a[10] is indexed from 0 to 9, not 1 to 10
- prototypes can be chosen to make things easy, or difficult.  Take time to select the simplest form you can get away with.  eg:

  `int *find(int arr[][COLS],int num);//pointer return`

for the stated purpose can be typed as:

```
int find(int arr[][COLS], int digit);// int return
```

- Function prtotypes that have a non-void return type should return something.  eg:  for the function:

  `int find(int arr[][COLS], int digit);`

the last lines in its implementation should be:

```
    return val;
}
```

Here is a simplification of a main and function that will search the rows of an array, and identify the first row that contains the highest count of a specified value in its columns:

```
#define COLS 5
#define ROWS  10

int find(int arr[][COLS], int digit)
{
    int row, col, rowKeep, rowMax=0, rowMaxKeep=0, rowCount[ROWS]={0} ;

    for(row=0;row<ROWS;row++)
    {
        for(col=0;col<COLS;col++)
        {
            if(arr[row][col] == digit)
            {
                rowCount[row]++;        
            }
            rowMax = rowCount[row];
            rowMax > rowMaxKeep ? rowMaxKeep = rowMax, rowKeep = row : 1 == 1;

        }
    }
    return rowKeep;
}

int main(void)
{
    //set of values to use in demonstration
    int arr[][COLS] = {{1,4,6,4,5},{5,5,6,7,8},{2,5,2,4,5},{1,1,2,8,9,},{5,5,5,3,2},{2,9,6,8,0},{1,3,6,5,4},{4,6,8,2,3},{1,4,5,5,6},{9,9,4,3,2}};
    int row = 0;

    row = find(arr, 5);//should find the 5th row (index value 4)
    row = find(arr, 1);//should find the 4th row (index value 3)
    row = find(arr, 4);//should find the 1st row (index value 0)

    return 0;
}
```